# How to iterate over months of the year efficiently in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsuserdefaults

I am iterating through the months of the year then when I get to Jan and go back to Dec the year also updates. The method I have created to do this is outlined below.

I am saving the date data into UserDefaults for the time being, when the viewwillappear method is called I access user defaults. When the user dose viewDidDisapear I then save user defaults with the updated day, month & year data...

It takes roughly 1-2 seconds for the UILabel to update the months name when the user selects either to increment months or decrement months button which both call this method.

```
- (void)shiftHistoricaldateWindowFromButtonPress:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *selectedButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    if (selectedButton.tag == 679) {
        // view history (backwards)
        _monthInt = _monthInt-1;
        if (_monthInt < 1) {
            _monthInt = 12;
            _yearInt = _yearInt - 1;
        }
         //enable button?
    } else {
        // view present (forward)
        // get present day
        NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
        NSInteger currentDayInteger = [dateComponents day];
        NSInteger currentMonthInteger = [dateComponents month];
        NSInteger currentYearInteger = [dateComponents year];

        if ((_monthInt != currentMonthInteger) || (_yearInt != currentYearInteger)) {
            _monthInt = _monthInt+1;
            if (_monthInt > 12) {
                _monthInt = 1;
                _yearInt = _yearInt + 1;
            }
        } else {
            // disable button?
        }

    }
    // update view
    // Read current date of historic graph (stored in NSUserDefaults)
    NSDateFormatter *dff = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    // set DateRageLabel
    _completeRangeString = [[dff monthSymbols] objectAtIndex:(_monthInt-1)];
    _dateRangeLabel.text = _completeRangeString;

}
```

Comment: There's nothing slow about the code you have shown. The problem could be elsewhere. But use Instruments to see what is going on! That's what it's for.

Comment: Generally delays on that scale are due to calling UIKit methods on a non-main queue rather than actual processing speed. I would start by making sure this is actually the code that's being called when you're having trouble. I would also make sure you're not accessing this label elsewhere, particularly on a background queue.